# ExtJS Groupable combobox with each group collapsible

Tags: extjs, combobox, grouping

As per my requirement, I want a combobox which will have its items grouped by some common property they have . Group name will be shown above items of that group in combo and it wont be selectable . But this group name will be clickable and on click of it , that group can be expanded/collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a tree in your combobox.

I know about a component thas has already done this. You can find it on the Sencha forums here: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?198856-Ext-ux-TreeCombo. Here are some examples: http://extjs.dariofilkovic.com/

You could alter/style it to your needs.

Comment: I have done https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1gl2 with the help of above link. But I am unable to select from combo as whenever I click or move mouse, combo collapses. Help ?